# python recursion on list of lists without isinstance (different)

Tags: python, recursion

I have an arbitrary list of arbitrary (but uniform) lists of numbers.  (They are the boundary coordinates of bins in an n-space whose corners I want to plot, but that's not important.)  I want to generate a list of all the possible combinations.  So: [[1,2], [3,4],[5,6]] produces [[1,3,5],[1,3,6],[1,4,5],[1,4,6],[2,3,5]...].

Can anyone help me improve this code?  I don't like the isinstance() call, but I can't figure out a more python-ish way to append the elements on the first pass, when the first arg (pos) is a list of numbers as opposed to a list of lists.

```
def recurse(pos, vals):
    out = []
    for p in pos:
        pl = p if isinstance(p,list) else [p]
        for x in vals[0]:
            out.append(pl + [x])
    if vals[1:]:
        return recurse(out, vals[1:])
    else:
        return out


a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[11,12,13]]

b = recurse(a[0], a[1:])
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

From your example it seems all you want is

```
from itertools import product
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[11,12,13]]
print list(product(*a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools

a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[11,12,13]]
iterator = itertools.product(*a)
result = [item for item in iterator.next()]
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more pythonic you have don't want to do type checking. Python is all about duct typing. What happens if you pass a tuple to the function (which should be more efficient).

You could try

```
if type(p) != list:
    try:
        p = list(p)
    except TypeError:
        p = [p]
pl = p
```

Answer (score 0):

When there is a library/module that does what you want, you should opt use it (+1 to all those who mentioned itertools.product). However, if you're interested in an algorithm to accomplish this, you are looking for a class of algorithms called [recursive descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)

```
answer = []
def recurse(points, curr=[]):
    if not points:
        answer.append(curr)
        curr = []
        return
    else:
        for coord in points[0]:
            recurse(points[1:], curr+[coord])
```